# Unique row in table based on two columns

Tags: database, ms-access, unique

I have table like shown below in MS Access

[image]

and as you can see line ID 9,10 are not unique based on the second and third column.

There is the realtionship 
[image]

I want to figure out somehow that only unique row can be inserted to table based on the second and third column, is that possible ?

Any tips can be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, you should create a compound primary key based on the 3 columns.

Read this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-change-a-table-s-primary-key-in-access-07b4a84b-0063-4d56-8b00-65f2975e4379

Take a look at: Set the primary key using fields you already have in Access

Attention to step 3.

As you data is text, be careful that user will select this by drop-down or radio buttons instead of typing in order to avoid duplicated rows by user mistyping.

Comment: Hi, I have made the compund primary key, but I was still able to insert a non unique row.

Comment: In this compound primary key do not include ID field. Please, trying again but be sure the ID field does not get a key symbol on it. Ok?

Comment: Yeah, now I got it. Works as I wanted to. Thanks mate :)